# How to resize web page to fit windows when test web page on difference screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

How to resize web page to fit windows when test web page on difference screen resolution ?

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kzqu9s4s/) and snippet below:

```html
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content" style=" text-align: center; ">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
      <img src="https://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/thumb/6/69/Business_cat_exploitable.jpg/200px-Business_cat_exploitable.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When test on 1280 x 800 px resolution

[image]

And then test on 800 x 600 px resolution

[image]

I want to show on 800 x 600 px resolution like this , how can i do that ?

[image]

Comment: Use % on img size https://jsfiddle.net/kzqu9s4s/1/

Comment: @DaniP -- could you please tell me the way not to use % on img size ?

Comment: anyway you would need to use % ... to be responsive. Why not?

Comment: i have to resize all of my web page like fiverr http://i.imgur.com/m5Azyie.jpg

but fiverr not set image to % ? how do they do ?

Comment: ???? like wat? wat resize ? where ?

Comment: i looking code on fiverr.com they not use image width % but still resize web page. http://i.imgur.com/m5Azyie.jpg how can they do ?

Comment: using % on the containers ? background contain-cover?

Answer (score -1):

I would make the img 100% wide.

```
<style>
    #main, #content, img { display: block; width: 100%; }
</style>
```